# re/regex pattern for string python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex pattern to find all occurrences in a string for this:

```
string = "List[5] List[6], List[10], List[100:] List[-2:] List[-2]"
re.findall("List[(.*?)]" , string)
# Expected output ['5', '6', '10', '100:',  '-2:', '-2']
# Output: []
```

What would be a good regex pattern to get the numbers in between the indexes?

Answer (score 8):

Square brackets are special characters in [Regex's syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).  So, you need to escape them:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "List[5] List[6], List[10], List[100:] List[-2:] List[-2]"
>>> re.findall("List\[(.*?)\]", string)
['5', '6', '10', '100:', '-2:', '-2']
>>>
```

Comment: In [101]: re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", string)
    Out[101]: ['5', '6', '10', '100:', '-2:', '-2'] works.

Comment: @kracekumar - The code in your comment does not work (it returns an empty list).  The code in your answer _does_ work, but you should mention that it will get everything that is inside square brackets.  For the OP's sample, this is fine, but it may not be appropriate behavior elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying `iCodez` answer a bit.

```
In [102]: import re

In [103]: string = "List[5] List[6], List[10], List[100:] List[-2:] List[-2]"

In [105]: re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", string)
Out[105]: ['5', '6', '10', '100:', '-2:', '-2']
```

Above will extract any character inside square bracket. If the string contains `List[5] Add[3]` output will be `[5, 6]`

```
In [115]: string = "List[4] tuple[3]"

In [116]: re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", string)
Out[116]: ['4', '3']
```

Above method will extract any characters inside square bracket.